# Primefaces CellEditEvent returns same object for both getOldValue and getNewValue method

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

**Code to generate datatable**

```
  public DataTable getDataTable(DataTable myDataTable,List<? extends ExcelTableModel> value,List<String> attributes){
    FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            Application application = fc.getApplication();
            ExpressionFactory ef = application.getExpressionFactory();
            ELContext elc = fc.getELContext(); 

                int i=0;
                for(String attribute:attributes){
                ValueExpression valueExp = ef.createValueExpression(elc, "#{mydata." + attribute + "}", Object.class);



                HtmlOutputText output = (HtmlOutputText)application.createComponent(HtmlOutputText.COMPONENT_TYPE );
                output.setValueExpression("value", valueExp);
                output.setId(attribute+"output"+i);



                InputText input = (InputText)application.createComponent(InputText.COMPONENT_TYPE );
                input.setValueExpression("value", valueExp);
                input.setStyle("color:black");
                input.setId(attribute+"input"+i);


                CellEditor editor = (CellEditor)application.createComponent(CellEditor.COMPONENT_TYPE );

                editor.getFacets().put("output", output);
                editor.getFacets().put("input", input); 

                Column dataColumn = new Column();
                dataColumn.setHeaderText(attribute);
                dataColumn.getChildren().add(editor);

            myDataTable.getChildren().add(dataColumn);
             i++;
       }
    return myDataTable;
}
```

**Datatable binding code**

```
<h:form id="form">    
    <p:dataTable 
              id="table" 
              var="mydata" 
              value="#{dynamicColumnBean.linkedList}" 
              binding="#{dynamicColumnBean.myDataTable}" 
              editable="true" 
              editMode="cell" 
              widgetVar="aList" 
              tableStyle="width:auto" 
              rowIndexVar="rowIndex">       

<p:ajax event="cellEdit" listener="#{dynamicColumnBean.onCellEdit}" update=":form:table"/>
    </p:dataTable>
 </h:form>
```

**onCellEdit event listener**

```
public void onCellEdit(CellEditEvent event) {

        Object oldValue = event.getOldValue();
        Object newValue = event.getNewValue();

    }
```

Every thing works but when i check onCellEdit event method it returns the same value for both getOldValue and getNewValue even i get the same id for both of them. I think i am missing something on generating component for datatable. Help me out what i am missing here thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it work if you create everything in  xhtml

Comment: Yes it works perfectly when i create with xhtml. The above code too create the same html output, tags and same script like that of generated from xhtml when i view its source code from page. But i always get the same new and old object even their id are same I think that event is taking the same component to the backing bean.